# The Sine Curve--trying to understand the curve based on the Unit Circle--why is my logic incorrect?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

When graphing y=sinx from x=0 to x=pi, I am coming up with a different graph, I think, that most experts and i have no idea why.

Here is my logic: I draw a unit circle, and I know that the sine function = opposite /hypotenuse of the acute angle of a right triangle. In a unit circle, since the Hypotenuse is always 1, the value of the sine function is just the perpendicular line starting from x=0 to x= pi/2 to x=pi to x=3/2pi to x=2pi as you "go around the circle". SO IN MY MIND, A SIN CURVE SHOULD BE THE EXACT SEMI-CIRCLE that is formed from x=0 to x=0, AND it follows, that the area of the sine curve from x=0 to x=pi can be found using the area of a circle formala for the unit circle and taking 1/2 of that value (since we are talking about a semicircle): So, A=1/2 (Area of unit circle), which equales 1/2 (pi*r^2), which in this case equals 1/2 pi.

This would make the integral of the graph from x=0 to x=pi equal 1/2 (area of unit circle), which would be pi/2 BUT THIS IS WRONG ACCORDING TO THE EXPERT I WATCHED, but WHY?????

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To correctly draw a graph of the sine function, your pencil should move from left to right at a constant speed as the relevant right triangle angle increases at a constant speed. This is not what happens when you draw a semicircle.

Comment: I will think about this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would help to see how the "density" of the sine segments for evenly-spaced angles differs from circle to wave.

[image]

Comment: Thank you--this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your semicircle has radius $r=1$ and therefore it rests on a diameter of length $2$, but the distance between $x=0$ and $x=\pi$ is $\pi$, which is greater than $3$. So your semicircle is not wide enough to be the graph of $\sin(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

To put it another way, when you draw a right triangle within the unit circle with vertex $A$ at the center of the circle, the vertical side of the triangle is the sine of the angle at $A$ and the horizontal side of the triangle is the cosine of the angle at $A$.
But when you plot the **graph** of $\sin(x)$, the coordinate $x$ must equal the length of the arc subtended by the angle at $A$. That is, this value of $x$ is measured along a curve, not along a straight line.

Comment: A bit late at responding, but thank you---this explanation really helped!